# SQL Query for getting maximum value from a column Joining from Another Table

Tags: mysql, sql

This is a slight variant of the question I asked here 
[SQL Query for getting maximum value from a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60884297/sql-query-for-getting-maximum-value-from-a-column#60884297)

I have a Person Table and an Activity Table with the following data

-- PERSON-----

[image]

------ACTIVITY------------

[image]

I have got this data in the database about users spending time on a particular activity.

I intend to get the data when every user has spent the maximum number of hours.

My Query is

```
Select p.Id as 'PersonId',
       p.Name as 'Name',
       act.HoursSpent as 'Hours Spent',
       act.Date as 'Date'
       From Person p
       Left JOIN (Select  MAX(HoursSpent), Date from Activity
                    Group By HoursSpent, Date) act
       on act.personId = p.Id
```

but it is giving me all the rows for Person and not with the Maximum Numbers of Hours Spent.
This should be my result.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several issues with your query:

- The subquery to get hours is aggregated by date, not person.
- You don't have a way to bring in *other* columns from `activity`.

You can take this approach -- `join`s and `group by`, but it requires two joins:

```
select p.*, a.*  -- the columns you want
from Person p left join
     activity a
     on a.personId = p.id left join
     (select personid, max(HoursSpent) as max_hoursspent
      from activity a
      group by personid
     ) ma
     on ma.personId = a.personId and
        ma.max_hoursspent = a.hoursspent;
```

Note that this can return duplicates for a given person -- if there are ties for the maximum.

This is written more colloquially using `row_number()`:

```
select p.*, a.*  -- the columns you want
from Person p left join
     (select a.*,
             row_number() over (partition by a.personid order by a.hoursspent desc) as seqnum
      from activity a
     ) a
     on a.personId = p.id and a.seqnum = 1
        ma.max_hoursspent = a.hoursspent;
```

Comment: let me try this.